# Как собирать sku, на php

Tags: php, массивы, json

Здравствуйте, разрабатываю дрошиппинг [есть json](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a8e3e38ff83ed9d76c2010b791629d2a) не как не понимаю как собирать массив со `sku` чтобы на выходе получил так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$sku['sku']['colors'][0]['name'] = 'как на картинке';
$sku['sku']['colors'][1]['name'] = 'чёрный';
$sku['sku']['size'][0] = '36';
$sku['sku']['size'][1] = '35';
print_r($sku);
```

в `json` все выброшено как попало, то есть один `json` и для `view` и для сравнения.

Comment: вместо картинки лучше бы привели желаемую структуру данных

Comment: Добавил, если вы смотрели json то наверняка заметили что там все в сплошную, например цвет: черный можно встретит сразу на двух индексах, логично было бы разделит цвет и размер.